# How to find .xml link and date only via Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match .xml link and expire date from following string.

> | iptv: { 1 } { 8000 } { localhost.test/categories/music.xml } { golden } { 000000 } { 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 } { 1 } | msg: { 1 } { 0 } { Welcome expire: 2020-01-20 } { 0 } { 0 } { 00 } { 0 }

I have tried the following rule to match it

```
/\}\s+\{\s+[^>]*xml\s+\}/igm
```

Honestly I don't understand regular expression and my try may be totally useless.

**My PHP code**:

```
$str = '| iptv: { 1 } { 8000 } { localhost.test/categories/music.xml } { golden } { 000000 } { 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 } { 1 } | msg: { 1 } { 0 } { Welcome expire: 2020-01-20 } { 0 } { 0 } { 00 } { 0 }';
$rule = '/\}\s+\{\s+[^>]*xml\s+\}/igm';
preg_match_all('', $str, $matches);
```

My desire output

`localhost.test/categories/music.xml` and `2020-01-20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you use matches from the first closing `}` until the closing `}` after .xml

You might use an alternation and a capturing group to match either one. For the date you could use a date like pattern. Note that it does not validate the date itself.

```
{[^[{}]*\h(\S+\.xml|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\h}
```

**Explanation**

- `{` Match literally
- `[^[{}]*\h` Negated character class, match 0+ times not `{` or `}`, then a horizontal whitespace char
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\S+\.xml` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char, `.` and xml
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` Match a date like pattern using digits and `-`
  - `)\h` Close group 1 and match a horizontal whitespace char
- `}` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FHb5wG/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/4AfZ7)

If you want group 1 and group 2, you might use:

```
{\h(\S+\.xml)\h}.*?{\h[^:]+:\h(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\h}
```

**Explanation**

- `{\h` Match `{` and a horizontal whitespace char
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\S+\.xml` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char, `.` and xml
- `)` Close group 1

  - `\h}` Match horizontal whitespace char and `}`
- `.*?{` Match any char except a newline 0+ times non greedy and match `{`
- `\h[^:]+:\h` Match 1+ times not :, then match :
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` Match a datelike pattern
- `)` Close group 2
- `\h}` Match horizontal whitespace char and `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXilkJ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/nYmAk)

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to vote up your answer cause of low reputation. But thanks for great help :)

Comment: You are welcome. The details are on the right side of the demo's on regex101. I could add them if you think it would be clearer.

Comment: Yup that would be more clear if details are in answer :)